# @Html.DropdownList not displaying choices by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using this to display a combobox on my webpage:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("Sortby", @Model.Values)
</div>
```

However the combobox does not display the items by default, only when hovering over the item:

Any ideas?

Comment: Which value you want ? and what is @Model.Values type??

Comment: It's a List of SelectListItems.

Comment: This seems like a css issue.  Try changing the color style on the select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the color on the select to something that would show up.  It looks like it is probably white right now.  Something like:

```
.dropdown select{
color: black;
}
```